# Windows phone 3D model rotation with touch

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, rotation, 3d-modelling

In my windows phone application I want to rotate an 3d model with using screen touch input.

The problem is;

At first everything is okay, I can move the model using touch but when I make the object upside down by the rotation in the X axis , the Y axis rotation becomes inverted. 
That is because my world axises are changed too.
I have tried many ways.

1st:

```
Matrix world = Matrix.Identity *Matrix.CreateRotationY( somerotation);
world = world * Matrix.CreateRotationX( somerotation );
world *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, 0, 0);
```

2nd:

```
    Matrix world = Matrix.Identity * Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(somerotation,somerotation,0);
world *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, 0.0f, zoomXY);
```

3rd:

```
  Matrix world = Matrix.Identity *Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(new Vector3(0, 1, 0),somerotation));
    world *= Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(new Vector3(1, 0, 0), somerotation));
    world *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(0,0,0);
```

4th

```
Matrix world = Matrix.Identity;
            world = Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.Up,somerotation);
            world *= Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.Right,somerotation);
            world *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, 0,0);
```

The result is the same.. Now my mind is rotating without control.

How can I use static axises that not change after the rotation? Or any other suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that nothing wrong with your math.  The 2nd axis motion is inverted because that is the correct motion when viewed from the opposite direction, which you caused by rotating the other axis.

Rather than creating a rotation about a fixed axis from scratch every frame, try storing some current orientation vectors (up and right, forward and left) and applying small incremental rotations about those orientations to a persistent world matrix.  You will also have to apply those same changes to your orientations, of course.

That way, no matter what direction your matrix is currently facing, you can always rotate relative to it and in the direction you want to go.

**Edit (for code):**

```
class gameclass
{
Vector3 forward = Vector3.UnitZ;    //persistent orientation variables
Vector3 left    = -1 * Vector3.UnitX;
Vector3 up      = Vector3.UnitY

Matrix world = Matrix.Identitiy;

InputClass inputputclass;           //something to get your input data

void Update()
{
Vector3 pitch = inputclass.getpitch();          //vertical swipe
forward = Vector3.transform(forward,
    Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(left, pitch));
up      = Vector3.transform(up,
    Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(left, pitch));

Vector3 yaw = inputclass.getyaw();              //horizontal swipe

forward = Vector3.transform(forward,
    Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(up, yaw));
left    = Vector3.transform(left,
    Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(up, yaw));

forward.Normalize(); left.Normalize(); top.Normalize();  //avoid rounding errors

world = Matrix.CreateWorld(
    postition                     //this isn't defined in my code
    forward,
    up);
}


}
```

It's not simple to have free, spherical roation.  :)

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I couldn't fully understand keeping the current vector. Current vector of the world or an identity matrix ? A brief pseudocode can be useful.

Comment: I am working on your code. My problem still exists. This didn't solve my problem. But you gave me a brilliant idea to solve the problem, so thank you very much for your consideration. I hope I can solve the problem.